# oj-select-one show undefined for all options

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, oracle-jet

i have an observable array that get its values from REST

```
$.getJSON(rootModel.soho()).
        then(function (StudentCourseView1) {
            $.each(StudentCourseView1.items, function () {
                self.data.push({
                    StudentId: this.StudentId,
                    CourseId: this.CourseId,
                    Enrollmentdate :this.Enrollmentdate,
                    Notes :this.Notes,
                    Id : this.Id,
                    CourseName : this.CourseName,
                    StudentName: this.StudentName
                });
            });
                    });
             self.dataSource = new oj.ArrayTableDataSource(
              self.data, 
              {idAttribute: 'Id'}
      );
```

and i have created select-one like this

```
 <oj-select-one id="select1" style="max-width:20em"
                 options={{data}}
                 value="{{data.Id}}"
                 options-keys="[[data.StudentName]]" >
</oj-select-one>
```

the select one show undefined for all it options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the ajax call is working, and there are no errors in console? Is the drop-down showing a list of blank values?

If yes, then the only missing element is adding `option-keys` attribute, to explain what data to show the user, and the key for each piece of data.

```
<oj-select-one id="select1" style="max-width:20em"
                 options={{data}}
                 options-keys="{{optionKeys}}" 
                 value="{{StudentId}}">
```

**JS**

```
//You can change this acc. to your convenience.
self.optionKeys = {value:"Id", label:"StudentName"};
```

Comment: the console is empty 
and the select one dont render on the page

will i didn't get the use of
self.optionKeys = {value:"Id", label:"StudentName"}; 

could u elaborate ?

Comment: options-keys is used to tell the `oj-select-one` component which 2 properties of `self.data` are to be used for 1) storing the selected value 2) displaying values in the UI. But if you're saying the `oj-select-one` doesn't render at all then the problem is elsewhere. Have you imported 'ojs/ojselectcombobox' in the define block? Have you defined `StudentId` as an observable?

Comment: the studentId is from the part of the observable array that is filled by the json.

i have added 'ofj/ojselectcombobox'

the console print the following error

Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "_ojCustomElement: function() {return {composite: info.composite}}"
Message: StudentId is not defined.

And the html show

options-keys="{{optionKeys}}" as static text

Comment: You need to define an observable separately to hold the value of the selected item. Add `self.studentId = ko.observable();` to your code.